# Which database should I use for this kind of time-series data?

Tags: database, postgresql, architecture

I have an application with several tables like `users`, `stories`, `comments` which consists fields like `id`, `rating`, `text`, `is_deleted` and so on.

There are >145 mil of comments, >7 mil of stories and >2.5 mil of users.

For each column in each table I have another table for storing versions, for example `comments` `rating` has table defined like this:

```
item_id uint64
timestamp int64
value int32
```

There are also the same tables for history of columns of other types like bool or string.

Now it works on postgres.

**What I want to achieve**: efficiently query the data, make distributions by day/hour and collect other statistics on my data.

**The problem** is that postgres is really slow, for example it takes >8 hours to make a distribution of comments by days and queries like `select count(*) where timestamp > x and timestamp < y` are also slow because postgres fetches all values and doesn't have any index for counts.

**The question**: Which database is more convenient for this kind of time-series data? Heard that there are influxdb, clickhouse and others, I don't have experience with any so it's hard to choose for me.

Comment: before migrating to the next database, have you checked the `explain analyze` of this query of yours? for this amount of data there is definitely a way to speed up the response time

Comment: You have a database containing 150M+ rows and an app using that database. The ONLY reasonable database is the already existing one. Don't try changing databases because you have written a bad query or have insufficient indexes. With the "change the DBMS for a slow query approach you will never do anything but migrate from one DBMS to another.

Comment: @Belayer, if one have chosen a wrong database for some operation it's not a good idea to stick with this database. Maybe I don't need to migrate and postgres is great for this kind of tasks, that's also the part of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like a data warehouse. Such a data warehouse needs careful modeling in *any* database system to work efficiently.

Typically, you have to pre-aggregate the data, for example per day, by using materialized views or triggers.